# Strange behaviour with rails localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization

I have set the default locale as `:es` in my application.rb:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :es
```

My `es.yml` file is looking like this:

```
es:
  hello:
    world: "Hola mundo"
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      post:
        title: "Titulo"
    errors:
      models:
        post:
          attributes:
            title:
              blank: "Hey el %{attribute} está en blanco!"
              too_short: "%{count} carácteres mínimos"
            text:
              blank: "Hey el %{attribute} está en blanco!"
              too_short: "%{count} carácteres mínimos"
```

I'm trying to make those nested translation keys work in views like `<%= t :'hello.world' %>`, with this configuration I get the following error:

`can not load translations from /home/edd/Programming/ruby/rails/blog/config/locales/en.yml: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (/home/edd/Programming/ruby/rails/blog/config/locales/en.yml): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 23 column 1>`

This error mentions `en.yml` which is structured like this:

```
en:
  hello:
    world: "Hello world"
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      post:
        title: "Title"
    ...
```

If I remove the nested part it starts working the t helper starts working:

```
en:
    world: "Hello world"
```

What could be happening here? thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: are you sure that all spaces on your file are actual spaces? There are no "odd characters" on it?

Comment: Based on the error message you should investigate leading characters at line 23 or the preceding row.

Answer (score 2):

We need to ensure space to over come this issue.

example:-

```
en:
  articles: 
    index:
      heading_list: 'Gurudath Articles List In English'
      description: 'Gurudath Articles Description In English'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there are any odd characters on line 23, e.g. a space in a series of tabs, etc.

If so, remove and ensure uniformity.